# How do I make images overlap in android using relativelayout

Tags: java, android, image, android-layout, android-relativelayout

[image]

Consider the image above.

The red lines indicate the image file borders, the black lines indicate the actual "useful" pixels of the image, and the white = transparent.

How would I go about getting these images positioned this way?

I'm not really sure this would make a difference in the way the above is done, but I am planning on implementing basic animations to each image (make each image rotate in respect to their respective centers).

This is what I have so far (positioning the 3 elements in the center, overlapping each other):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/img_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription = "@string/img1"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/img2"
    android:rotation="45"
    android:src="@drawable/img2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/img3"
    android:rotation="200"
    android:src="@drawable/img3" />
```

Thanks!

/e 1 - Thank you for editing in the image
   2 - I solved this problem through trial and error, thank you anyways!